# CakePHP error 404

Tags: php, cakephp

How can I have a custom layout for a 404 page in Cake? I know you can create your own view but I also want a custom layout for it as I don't want it inheriting my site design and want it to have a unique look and feel.

I've created my own views and then added my own `app_error` in `/app/` with the following code:

```
<?php

    class AppError extends ErrorHandler
{
    function error()
    {
        $this->layout = 'error';
    }
}



?>
```

But it doesn't load the error layout? Any ideas why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own `AppError` class (in `app/app_error.php` and override the `_outputMessage` method, something like:

```
class AppError extends ErrorHandler {
    function _outputMessage($template) {
        $this->controller->render($template, 'NAME OF THE LAYOUT');
        $this->controller->afterFilter();
        echo $this->controller->output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just create a file at `/views/errors/error404.thtml`. It may end in `.ctp` actually, but give both a shot.

Comment: Yeah thats the view though, but it still uses the default.ctp in `/views/layouts/` this is what I want to override.

Answer (score -1):

Create/edit the `app/views/errors/error404.ctp` page. See [CakePHP Error Handling](http://book.cakephp.org/#!/view/1188/Error-Handling).

Comment: what about changing the layout though. it wil still use the default.ctp file in `/views/layouts/`